# How to skip first two lines and last one line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have string value:

```
    str1 = """
          first line
          second line
          abc
          def
          xyz
          123
          lastline"""
```

How to skip first two lines and last line and print remaining lines.

Code: I tried and works for to skip first two lines

```
for index, line in enumerate(str1.split("\n")):
    if index <= 1:
        continue
    print line
```

Output getting from above code:

```
          abc
          def
          xyz
          123
          lastline
```

Expected output:

```
          abc
          def
          xyz
          123
```

Comment: `(if index <= 1) or (index >= len(str.split("\n")) - 1)`? Or better yet, precompute the number of lines and store it as a variable.

Comment: like `str1.split("\n")[2:-1]`?

Comment: Related: [understanding python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: `for index, line in enumerate(str1.split("\n")[2:-1])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines exists

Comment: Your're actually skipping the first three lines (the top line just has a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`string.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> str1.splitlines()[3:-1]
['          abc', '          def', '          xyz', '          123']
```

Note that the first line (index 0) is empty. It is terminated by the first `\n` directly after the opening double quotes.

Comment: I think that should be `[2:-1]`.

Comment: Actually it is `[3:-1]` because of the leading `\n`.

Comment: I am end up with using [3: -2] because I have last line is empty line. Shall i use filter to remove empty lines from the list?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. If you know the number of lines, even the empty ones, the slice approach should work fine. But if you want to remove empty lines somewhere in the file, filter them.